# What is "Persistent Bitmap Caching"?

Tags: remote-desktop

The Remote Desktop client shows me this option to connect:

[image: Remote Desktop Connection Window]

What does this option do?

Comment: @ultrasawblade: Ah, I see they renamed the setting across Windows releases. Agreed; voted to close :)

Answer (score 1):

"Reconnect if the connection is dropped": This will help the remote Desktop Connection to attempt to reconnect to the remote computer if the connection is severed.

Persistent Bitmap Caching, that pictures and other bitmap assets are mainly put away on the machine for reusing them later. Thusly, the remote server or PC doesn't send pictures twice decreasing the amout of information sent and sparing your bandwith use.

The choice bodes well for moderate (low transmission capacity) associations, less on the off chance that you associate with a machine in the same neighborhood.

On the off chance that you empower the choice, the Remote Desktop customer stores bitmaps into a BMC record found on the customer hard circle.

Comment: That option is fairly self explanatory :)